# Evitar que elementos repetidos nunca esten a la par dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, nodejs

me encuentro con el siguiente problema, tengo un array de `n` posiciones, ejemplo:

```
    [1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 7, 2, 3];
```

Como se puede observar tengo elementos repetidos, es decir `"2, 1"` (de momento no es el problema, elementos repetidos son validos); necesito aplicar un `shuffle` al array, es decir cambiar sus posiciones aleatoriamente, para eso tengo el siguiente metodo:

```javascript
    const shuffle = (array) => {
      let length = array.length;
      let randomIndex;
      while (length !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
        length--;
        array[length] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = array[length];
      }
      return array;
    };
```

Me funciona totalmente bien, me cambia las posiciones aleatoriamente algo así:

```
    [4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 1, 1];
```

Lo que yo deseo es evitar que existan elementos que se pongan a la par, en este caso los números `2` estan a la par, es decir las posiciones `3 y 4 = 2`

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Me parece que no estás contemplando muchos de los posibles casos. ¿Qué pasa si el arreglo es `[2,2,1,2]`? ¿Qué harías?

Answer (score 2):

Tu función de shuffle daña el contenido del array:

```js
const shuffle = (array) => {
  let length = array.length;
  let randomIndex;
  while (length !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
    length--;
    array[length] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = array[length];
  }
  return array;
};

console.log(shuffle([1,2,3,4]))
```

Lo que puedes hacer es hacer shuffle al array hasta que no existan 2 posiciones repetidas.

```js
let datos = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8];
function shuffle(array) {
  return [...array].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}

const tieneValorRepetido = (array) => {
  for(const [index, value] of array.entries()){
    if(index < array.length-1){
      if(value === array[index+1]){
        //Si valor es igual al valor que le sigue
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}


do{
  datos = shuffle(datos);
}while(tieneValorRepetido(datos));


console.log(datos)
```

Esto en el caso en que el array siempre se pueda ordenar sin que hayan elementos repetidos... porque sino, por ejemplo un array como `[1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1]` pues entraría en un ciclo infinito.